# Error in SQL statement: ParseException: SQL CTE

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, common-table-expression

```
  %sql
    create table temptable 
    as 
    with dupes as 
    (select component, count(case when type = 'Person' then 1 end) person_ct from components 
    group by component 
    having person_ct > 1)
```

Throws me an error as

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'(', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'FROM', 'MAP', 'REDUCE', 'SELECT', 'TABLE', 'VALUES'}(line 6, pos 21)

== SQL ==
create table temptable 
as 
with dupes as 
(select component, count(case when type = 'Person' then 1 end) person_ct from components 
group by component 
having person_ct > 1)
---------------------^^^
```

Dont understand the error here.

Answer (score 0):

The **text**, **image**, and **ntext** data types cannot be used in a HAVING clause. you cannot use an alias name in having a clause. you have to give same count expression instead of person_ct..

**Code should look like this :**

```
%sql
    create table temptable
    as
    with dupes as
    (select component, count(case when type = 'Person' then 1 end) person_ct from components
    group by component 
    having count(case when type = 'Person' then 1 end)> 1)
```